# Connected to mysql database but cannot print the data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I connected successfully to my database and the I tried to print my data but I can only see the "Connected succesfully" line in the browser. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$db=mysqli_connect("host","root","pass","dbase");

if (!$db) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "SELECT username FROM students";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "username: " . $row["username"].  "<br>";
   }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$db->close();
?>
```

So the issue was that SELinux was blocking remote connections from PHP scripts executed by Apache web server.
The setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1 in the terminal did the trick.

Comment: What is in the PHP error log?

Comment: Simple: You didn't select a database. You're also using the wrong variable `$conn` it's `$db`.

Comment: If you're having trouble with bugs, why would you suppress error messages with `@`? It seems like such messages would be useful.

Comment: I am new in php-mysql, let me try your suggestions and i will let you know the results

Comment: @Christakitos Al and I both posted answers for you below quite a long time ago and haven't had a response from you. Whether you saw them, is unknown, so go over them carefully.

Comment: I did check them and they were very helpful but i found the real issue. I edited the original post with the solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Christakitos Great, but the way Stack works is that when someone provides a solution, an answer should be accepted in order to mark the question as solved. Right now, your question is still considered as open. I myself went through a lot of trouble typing out a rather well-explained answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36190126/1415724

Comment: @Christakitos you also can't go edit your original question and showing correct syntax. People may downvote both our answers because people will say *"There's nothing wrong with the guy's code"*. What you did was wrong.

Comment: @Fred -ii And this answer helped me a lot, I did find the solution a few minutes ago and then i edited the post for you to know i found it. Don't you see the updates? I'm really sorry i am learning how to use the stack.

Comment: @Fred -ii Ok, thank you for your time and your help. I also did learn a few things for stack from you.

Comment: @Christakitos You're welcome, always glad to help, *cheers* and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Note to future readers. The OP edited their question with the corrected syntax after answers were posted and this answer was based on their original post:

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36189996/2

and added:

> *"So the issue was that SELinux was blocking remote connections from PHP scripts executed by Apache web server. The setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1 in the terminal did the trick."*

Firstly, you didn't select a database.

and `if (!db)` needs to be changed to `if (!conn)` and `if ($db->connect_error)` to `if ($conn->connect_error)`. The same variable needs to be used throughout your code.

You're also using the wrong variable `$db` it's `$conn` (or whatever you want to use, but as I said above, you need to use the same variable for your connection and for the query.

Error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have told you about an undefined variable.

Therefore:

```
$conn = @mysqli_connect("host","root","pass", "your_database");
```

Sidenote: `host` I take it is only representative of the host you're using. If you're on your own PC, you would use `localhost` and accessing that file as `http://localhost/file.php` instead of `file///file.php` if that is what you're doing and will not work. The web browser will not parse PHP directives like that and you need to install a webserver/PHP in order for it to work, including MySQL.

Read the manual on connecting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

and remove the `@` symbols while testing. They are error suppressors.

Check for errors with http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Example from the manual:

Sidenote: `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` or if hosted, use the setting they gave you to use.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 0):

You use another variable than you connected to the database!

You connected to `$db` but perform the query with `$conn`.
Also, in the check if the database connection could be established you do not have the `$` before `db`.

It always helps a lot when you have in a terminal window the PHP error log open. 99% of errors can be fixed by your self.

Comment: You saw my comment I take it ;-) because you completely changed your answer from your original.

Comment: @Fred-ii- My 1st answer was wrong due the unformatted text. I oversaw the `if`. Then I deleted the post because this was not the problem. While formatting the code - I do not have enough reputation that it is immediately published - I saw the real error and undeleted my post and wrote my answer. But yes, you are the best.

Comment: No problemo Al - *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- De nada mi señor!